# Making a sprite move, need the sprite to stay in the postion he last moved in

Tags: java, applet

I'm making a java game, and when the user presses some keys, the sprite moves in that direction, and it changes the sprite to match the direction that the user is inputting.
If you want to see the current game, head to this website: http://thetutspace.org/acropolis/beta/

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    int x_posI = (int) x_pos;
    int y_posI = (int) y_pos;


    if (downPressed && leftPressed) {
        g.drawImage(hero225, x_posI, y_posI, this);
        spr270 = false;
    } else if (downPressed && rightPressed) {
        spr270 = false;
        g.drawImage(hero135, x_posI, y_posI, this);
    } else if (upPressed && rightPressed) {
        spr270 = false;
        g.drawImage(hero45, x_posI, y_posI, this);
    } else if (upPressed && leftPressed) {
        g.drawImage(hero315, x_posI, y_posI, this);
        spr270 = false;
    } else if (leftPressed == true) {
        g.drawImage(hero270, x_posI, y_posI, this);
        spr270 = true;
    } else if (rightPressed == true) {
        g.drawImage(hero90, x_posI, y_posI, this);  
        spr270 = false;
    } else if (upPressed == true) {
        g.drawImage(hero, x_posI, y_posI, this);
        spr270 = false;
    } else if (downPressed == true) {
        g.drawImage(hero180, x_posI, y_posI, this); 
        spr270 = false;
    }
        else{
            g.drawImage(hero, x_posI, y_posI, this);
        }
    if(spr270) {
        g.drawImage(hero270, x_posI, y_posI, this);
    }
```

When I press LEFT, this is what happens:
i.stack.imgur[dot]com/owT3z.png

When I let go, this is what I happens:
i.stack.imgur.com/2Wrjr[dot]png

How can I make it so the character stays facing left?

Comment: unrelated to your problem but related to readability: why have `if (foo == true) {`?  Why not `if (foo) {`?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, thanks.

Comment: Now as to your current problem, I for one am confused on just what your problem is.  You may want to a paragraph or two of description to your original post describing the details of your problem and what's not working when you've tried to solve it.

Comment: If you play the game at http://thetutspace.org/acropolis/beta/ you can see what the problem is.

Comment: @Deza: I'll take a pass on that, but I think I speak for most in preferring that you take the effort to explain it to us. It is you asking for the free advice, no?

Comment: I added images, but it seems someone has already solved it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is inside paint( Graphics g ) method, right?

Add volatile Image field sprite to your class ("protected volatile Image sprite;").
Change logic to:

```
int x_posI = (int) x_pos;
int y_posI = (int) y_pos;

if (downPressed && leftPressed) {
    this.sprite = hero225;
} else if (downPressed && rightPressed) {
    this.sprite = hero135;
} else if (upPressed && rightPressed) {
    this.sprite = hero45;
} else if (upPressed && leftPressed) {
    this.sprite = hero315;
} else if (leftPressed == true) {
    this.sprite = hero270;
} else if (rightPressed == true) {
    this.sprite = hero90;
} else if (upPressed == true) {
    this.sprite = hero;
} else if (downPressed == true) {
    this.sprite = hero180;
}

// this.sprite will contain value set on last "movement"
g.drawImage(this.sprite, x_posI, y_posI, this);
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic. Thank you :)